# Gem::InstallError: The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I installed Ruby on windows 32-bit, with Ruby version 2.0.0, Rails version 4.2.6 and having gem version 2.6.4.
Then i created a new application to check whether Ruby On Rails is working proper or not. After creating app, I got same error for 3 to 4  gems and the error is

> Gem::InstallError: The 'json' native gem requires installed build too
>   ls.
>   Please update your PATH to include build tools

I followed the given answers in [Gem::installerror: the 'json' native gem requires installed build tools. Please update our PATH to include build tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709334/geminstallerror-the-json-native-gem-requires-installed-build-tools-please)

But i was not able to find the solution..
 Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. All of this seems to be unnecessarily complicated.