# Gosu/Ruby fails to install

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, libgosu

Gosu fails to install on my Mountain Lion (10.8.3).
Here's the error I get:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing gosu:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
The Gosu gem requires some libraries to be installed system-wide.
See the following site for a list:
https://github.com/jlnr/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Linux

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:338:in `symlink': File exists - ../linux/gosu.bundle or ../lib/gosu.bundle (Errno::EEXIST)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:338:in `ln_s'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1418:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:336:in `ln_s'
from extconf.rb:99
```

What I tried so far:

- Checked that I've got Command line tools installed in My XCode. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389301/os-x-rails-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension) guy had same problem. But we evidently have different source(s) of problem(s).
- Tried installing dependencies from the rubygame website, appearently helped [this guy](http://www.libgosu.org/cgi-bin/mwf/topic_show.pl?tid=883). Installed the libraries like this guy.
- Changed the path to put */usr/local/bin* in front of */usr/bin/*. That didn't help either.
- Tried to install Rubygame gem : And same problem!
- Tried to install SDL gem : Same problem!
- So I decided to try to install something different: the Cake gem. It worked!
- I decided to give up and ask the question in stackoverflow.
- I typed my problem in stackoverflow.

So what could the problem be?

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the question? I'll prepare my questions better next time. Why did no one "accept" this question?

Comment: I solved this issue by using Rbenv as suggested by the kind folks at reddit.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue.  After tinkering in my Path forever, I downloaded and ran Jewelrybox. Afterwards, I had it reinstall ruby-1.9.3 -p448, during which it ran diagnostics. Thankfully was able to install gosu after that.

Try that out, hopefully it works for you too.

Comment: For me, it was simply using Ruby 1.9.3 instead of 2.0