# Installing Dashing Error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dashing

I am trying to install Dashing Framework on my Macbook Air Os X Mavericks running Ruby 2.0.0.

When I run `sudo gem install dashing` I get the following errors:

```
    ERROR:  Error installing dashing:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/ext/gem_make.out
```

Any thoughts on this? I'm not sure how to get this to install properly..

Answer (score 2):

I installed Dashing on a fresh Mavericks install today. I would recommend **using Ruby 1.9.3. as per the ["Getting Started" section](http://shopify.github.io/dashing/).**

**Here is what I did:**

If you haven't upgraded Xcode yet you should do so, open the terminal and type:

`xcode-select --install`

This will install xcode command tools.

Install RVM (development version):
`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash`

Watch the output, you have to perform one more step:

`source --your path--.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Install Ruby 193

`rvm install ruby-1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`

*I ran with --with-gcc=clang to get around "error: C compiler cannot create executables"*

Once installed, you may then use it by executing the following command:

`rvm use 1.9.3`

And confirm it is in use

`ruby -v`

Then as per Dashing docs:

`gem install dashing`

`dashing new sweet_dashboard_project` *or what you want to name it*

Change your directory to sweet_dashboard_project and bundle gems

`bundle`

`dashing start`

Browse localhost:3030

Answer (score 0):

You need install ruby development package in mac os

see related question

- [Unable to install gem - Failed to build gem native extension - cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767725/unable-to-install-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cannot-load-such)
- [OS-X, Rails: "Failed to build gem native extension"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389301/os-x-rails-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Answer (score 0):

try the below command and run `sudo gem install dashing`

```
yum -y install gcc mysql-devel ruby-devel rubygems
```