# Ruby crashes when starting application. Is it the environment?

Tags: ruby, crash, dashing

I'm attempting to install a ruby application, however it crashes as soon as I start it. 
I'm trying to figure out of this is a problem with the application, or a problem with my environment (likely the second).

The ruby installation steps are located here:

https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/wiki/Dashing-Workshop

I'm using Mac, so I"m trying this with rbenv

```
rbenv shell 2.0.0-p247
gem install dashing
dashing new monitorama
cd monitorama
bundle

dashing start
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin13.2.0]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0010 p:-17575731806276 s:0030 e:000029 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0009 p:---- s:0028 e:000027 CFUNC  :require
c:0008 p:0079 s:0024 e:000023 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:8 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0022 e:000021 CFUNC  :require
c:0006 p:0055 s:0018 e:000017 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin.rb:7 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0016 e:000015 CFUNC  :require
c:0004 p:0007 s:0012 e:000011 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/bin/thin:5 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0010 e:000009 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0118 s:0006 E:002188 EVAL   /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/thin:23 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0006d8 TOP    [FINISH]

/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/thin:23:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/bin/thin:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/bin/thin:5:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin.rb:7:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/thin

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/rbconfig.rb
    4 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    5 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    6 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    7 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    8 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
    9 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   10 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   11 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   12 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   13 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   14 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   15 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
   16 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/pathname.bundle
   17 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb
   18 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/constants.rb
   19 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
   20 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/etc.bundle
   21 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb
   22 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
   23 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb
   24 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   25 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
   26 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb
   27 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/gem_path_manipulation.rb
   28 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
   29 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/match_platform.rb
   30 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
   31 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/version.rb
   32 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb
   33 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/settings.rb
   34 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
   35 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/digest.bundle
   36 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/digest.rb
   37 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/digest/sha1.bundle
   38 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb
   39 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb
   40 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
   41 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb
   42 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
   43 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/source.rb
   44 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb
   45 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb
   46 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ftp.rb
   47 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/http.rb
   48 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/https.rb
   49 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldap.rb
   50 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldaps.rb
   51 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/mailto.rb
   52 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri.rb
   53 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/socket.bundle
   54 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb
   55 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/fcntl.bundle
   56 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb
   57 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb
   58 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/openssl.bundle
   59 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/bn.rb
   60 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/cipher.rb
   61 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/stringio.bundle
   62 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/config.rb
   63 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/digest.rb
   64 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/x509.rb
   65 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb
   66 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/ssl.rb
   67 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl.rb
   68 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/securerandom.rb
   69 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/resolv.rb
   70 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
   71 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/text.rb
   72 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/name_tuple.rb
   73 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb
   74 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
   75 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/strscan.bundle
   76 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/source/path.rb
   77 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/source/git.rb
   78 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb
   79 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb
   80 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb
   81 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb
   82 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb
   83 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb
   84 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb
   85 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/index.rb
   86 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb
   87 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/endpoint_specification.rb
   88 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb
   89 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb
   90 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/date_core.bundle
   91 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/date/format.rb
   92 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/date.rb
   93 /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/time.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

I've tried on 2 different macs, both running OSX 10.9.x with various versions of ruby. All of them produce this crash.

Since I haven't worked with ruby much, or rbenv, I need to know where the fault lies.

Can anyone identify whether this crash is a problem with the ruby application, or the environment?

**Update**

I tried again this time changing the following variables

mac osx => linux cent 6.5
rbenv   => RVM
ruby 2.0.0 => ruby 2.1.1

It crashed again here is the stack trace

https://gist.github.com/spuder/989132dbc2f7d5e66ca0

**Update2**

I noticed that it mentioned something about 'thin'
This is what happens when I try and install thin

```
gem install thin
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed thin-1.6.2
Parsing documentation for thin-1.6.2
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/thin_parser.bundle, skipping
1 gem installed
```

**Update3**

I uninstalled the gems, ran a gem clean, then tried again using ruby 1.9.3 as suggested in comments.

I've copied the results to this gist. It crashes with the same error

https://gist.github.com/spuder/f07c52fe23d573ba723e

Comment: Any reason you're using Ruby 2? I just tried it with ruby 1.9.3p385 and that seems to work fine. Sure Ruby 2 might be already stable but I doubt that all common gems are already compatible with it.

Comment: @DavidOngaro I'm still pretty new to ruby, I assumed the newer ruby would be better. Maybe I should try again with an older ruby.

Comment: Yeah, the difference between Ruby 1.9 and 2.0 is big. I think Ruby 1.9 is much more production proven (and hardened). But if you're using rbenv it's easy to switch ruby versions.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820033/installing-dashing-error?rq=1. Seems to be a similar problem with dashing and Ruby 2.0

Comment: Thanks @DavidOngaro I tried again with ruby 1.9.3, but it still crashes. I've put the full details in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many more hours, I figured it out.

Combinations that failed

ruby 2.0.0
Mac
rbenv

ruby 1.9.3
Mac
rbenv

ruby 2.1.x
Mac
rbenv

ruby 2.0.0
Linux (cent 6.4)
rbenv

As soon as I switched from rbenv to RVM, everything worked perfectly on my Mac.