# Can't install Jekyll on MacOS Sierra 10.12.1

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll, blogs

I'm trying to install **Jekyll** using:

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

but I get a error, I had found a solution on early mac version not for *Sierra*

this is the output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.17/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170117-1518-aaehhb.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.17 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-16/2.0.0/ffi-1.9.17/gem_make.out
```

thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the [Ruby DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/). Depending on your installation of Ruby, you have to select the correct way to install it.

Comment: Hi @deveth0, can't find any link for mac on ruby download page website, just for windows only, anyway thank you, i'm keeping searching!

Comment: I think this thread should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389301/os-x-rails-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Comment: Yes it's helpful, i'm going to install Developer Tool and I hope get this done!