# Error when installing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I got the following error messages when having typed: 
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc

mklog file contents as attached at https://www.scribd.com/document/358631437/mklog-msg?secret_password=SrMhX0TsFWsPKAeMdtUI

Steps done prior to this, to troubleshoot:
 1. installed xCode 3 times via AppStore
 2. Accepted terms and conditions of xcode
 3. tried with commands - gem install nokogiri
sudo gem install rails
gem update --system

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/ext/nokogiri
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170911-32840-12em9fb.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.2.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Fix-comparison-with-root-node-in-xmlXPathCmpNodes.patch
    - 0002-Fix-XPointer-paths-beginning-with-range-to.patch
    - 0003-Disallow-namespace-nodes-in-XPointer-ranges.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
Running git apply with /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/patches/libxml2/0001-Fix-comparison-with-root-node-in-xmlXPathCmpNodes.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-XPointer-paths-beginning-with-range-to.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/patches/libxml2/0003-Disallow-namespace-nodes-in-XPointer-ranges.patch... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
    unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:815:27: warning: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
  CC       error.lo
  CC       parserInternals.lo
  CC       parser.lo
  CC       tree.lo
  CC       hash.lo
  CC       list.lo
  CC       xmlIO.lo
xmlIO.c:1450:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
    ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;
                                                   ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:400:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:371:in `chdir'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:371:in `execute'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:114:in `compile'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:153:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:365:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:364:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:548:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.0/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS-X, Rails: "Failed to build gem native extension"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389301/os-x-rails-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Comment: Did not find 'command line tools' under preference / components section. Verified that they and  gcc were installed using xcode-select -p and  gcc --version

Comment: I think you should just install command line tools. Try another way like this http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html

Comment: installed with $ gcc confirming this via the following:

xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.

Comment: Did you check `/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.0/mkmf.log` to see what the error actually is?

Comment: I did and its contents were as attached above. Somehow managed to solve this following steps of an online resource (where prior resources did not work for me) - where I started from scratch installing everything from Homebrew, Ruby, xCode, the command line tools, Rails where it worked 100% perfectly without error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow managed to solve this following steps of an online resource (where prior resources did not work for me) - where I started from scratch installing everything from Homebrew, Ruby, xCode, the command line tools, Rails where it worked 100% perfectly without error messages.